# Unexpected Response Code 404 Instagram API

Tags: android, instagram-api

I am trying to send a request for user feed -

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token={}
```

but getting this 404 code which means that server does not understand the request. I built the app before they updated the API and is now in sandbox mode with the new API guidelines in effect but this used to work before 1st June, 2016.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram yesterday on 1. June update policy, in the brief before 1. June anyone can get api and explore whole Instagram without some checks by Instagram team, after 1. June Instagram team will check each app before they go live, you need login in [instagram.com/developer](http://instagram.com/developer) and create app, then you choose which type of data you need and describe for what, and send to Instagram team for check, they usually answer in 3 working days ...